# How to store the retrieved Firestore documents in an array using map()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

In Vue 3, I am trying to store the result (documents) of a Firestore collection query in an array. The official docs only describe this using forEach() but I would like to return a new array using map() as it seems to be faster for large collections.

It only logs "[object Object],[object Object]" to the console.

This is my code:

```
setup() {

    const myList = ref([])

    projectFirestore.collection("testcollection").where("name", "==", "Mike")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        myList.value = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
        })
        console.log('This is my list: ' + myList.value)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //error
    });

    return { myList }
}
```

How can I get the actual data in the myList array?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That is the data itself and you can use it to map your UI. Try `JSON.stringify(myList)`. This will log the array as a string.

Comment: As @Dharmaraj already mentioned `JSON.stringify(someObject)` is your friend..